# Programmatically notification on apple watch. (WatchOS 3)

Tags: swift, watchkit, apple-watch, watchos, watchos-3

How I can programmatically make the notification appear only on the apple watch and only when the event occurs. I searched for a long time on the Internet and in the documentation but did not find the answer

Answer (score 1):

There is no way for you to decide whether the notification appears on the Watch or on the Phone, the system handles this automatically and you cannot change this behaviour.

The notification only appears on the Watch if all of the below requirements are met:

- The connected iPhone's screen is locked
- The watch is worn by the user in case WristDetection is turned on
- Do not disturb mode is turned off on the Watch