# Notifications on watchOs

Tags: ios, swift, apple-watch, watchos

I made an app. And I send push notifications to the app. And I want to received them on watchos too. Do I have to make a project for watchOs, and make an app? Or automatically I received all push notifications from my iphone (especially from my app) on watchOs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iOS automatically sends the received (push) notifications to watchOS assuming the notification settings for the specific app that received the notification are set up to allow notifications on the Apple Watch (this is controlled by the user from the Watch app on iOS).

There's no need for a watchOS app to receive notifications on the Apple Watch, an iOS app is sufficient.

It is also important to note that system only displays notifications on the Apple Watch in some specific scenarios, which you can see in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45323987/4667835).